# rewrite the code cocos2d (objective-c) on cocos2d-x (c++)

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, translate

Now rewrite the code from cocos2d (objective-c) to cocos2d-x (c + +) and collided with a problem:
I have two classes, two CCLayer. In one class there CCMenu by pressing the button calls the second class:

```
CCMenuItem * button = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage: @ "1.png" selectedImage: nil block: ^ (id sender) {
             
              HelloWorldLayer * helloWorldLayer = (HelloWorldLayer *) [self.parent getChildByTag: 777];
              [helloWorldLayer createSprite: self];
          }];
```

And in the second grade, I assign Layer tag:

self.tag = 777;

and that method:

```
  - (void) createSprite: (id) sender {
..}
```

How to rewrite this code in C + +?))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple.

Let class in which menu is Class- A

```
CCMenuItem * button=CCMenuItemImage::create("normal", "selected", "disable", menu_selector(A::Method));
```

The Method is

```
void A::Method(CCObject *pSender){
 HelloWorldLayer * helloWorldLayer = (HelloWorldLayer *)this->parent->getChildByTag(777);
 helloWorldLayer->createSprite(this);
}
```