# How to call a method of the first class of the second, by pressing the button?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I can not make a call to a method of a class from another class :[rewrite the code cocos2d (objective-c) on cocos2d-x (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378557/rewrite-the-code-cocos2d-objective-c-on-cocos2d-x-c)

Error:

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(273): error C2562: std::_Pmd_caller<_Ret,_Arg0>::_Call_pmd: функция типа "void", возвращающая значение
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Arg0=cocos2d::Object
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(271): см. объявление "std::_Pmd_caller<_Ret,_Arg0>::_Call_pmd"
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Arg0=cocos2d::Object
1>          ]
```

Not become fully kidat.Tam 20 more lines of the same

HudLayer.cpp

```
CCMenuItem *button = CCMenuItemImage::create("1.png","1.png",menu_selector(HelloWorld::createSprite));
```

HelloWorld.cpp

```
void HelloWorld::createSprite(CCObject *sender)
{

    _sprite->initWithFile("bird.png");
    _sprite->setPosition(ccp(x,y));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the IronMan.h you have to declare

static void playClicked();

In the Avenger.cpp you can use this method

```
 CCSize *screenSize   = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
CCPoint pointOrigin  = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();
float x = screenSize.width;
float y = screenSize.height;*
```

CCWidgetLayout* widgetLayout = CCWidgetLayout::create();

addChild(widgetLayout);

```
CCButton* playButton = CCButton::create("btn1.png", "btn2.png", "btn3.png");
playButton->setPosition(x/1.2f,y/1.5f);
playButton->setClickSelector(this,click_selector(IronMan::playClicked));
widgetLayout->addChild(playButton,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do like this..

```
  CCMenuItem *button = CCMenuItemImage::create("1.png","1.png",menu_selector(HudLayer::createSpriteMethod));

void HudLayer::createSpriteMethod(CCObject *sender)
   {
    _helloWorld//assuming you have instance of HelloWorld
    _helloWorld->createSprite(sender);
  }
```

for **HelloWorld::createSprite**.....it should be static method.,nothing good comes from it.